# eclipse enquiry

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse helios. I have jdk 1.6 installed. I am not getting dynamic web project in the new project pane. What could be the problem? Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the package you downloaded. I believe that project type requires "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers", or else you have to download the required plugin from the update manager.